# How to change gravity (win_gravity) of a window?

Tags: x11, skype, window-management

Skype always pops messages at lower right corner of screen.
Does changing widow gravity ([win_gravity](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/gravity.html), defaults to NorthWest) for Skype alters pop-ups position (what I want to do actually)?

Got no success under [WMII](https://code.google.com/p/wmii/) for non-supported feature (WM doesn't support _NET_MOVERESIZE_WINDOW. Gravity will be ignored).
Used `xprop` and `wmctrl` but no luck:

```
% wmctrl -vr skype -e "X,0,0,-1,-1" ### X: 0, 1, 2...
envir_utf8: 1
Invalid type of _NET_WM_NAME property.
Invalid type of WM_NAME property.
Using window: 0x016003c2
grflags: 775
WM doesn't support _NET_MOVERESIZE_WINDOW. Gravity will be ignored.
```

Couldn't figure out what to set with xprop:

```
% xprop -name skype -set "window gravity" "NorthEast"
% xprop -name skype -set "window-gravity" "7"
% xprop -name skype -set "win_gravity" "7"
% xprop -name skype -set "win_gravity" "NorthEast"
% xprop -name skype -set "win_gravity" "NorthEastGravity"
```

All gave me an error:

```
xprop: error: unsupported conversion for win_gravity (or whatever first -set arg was)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is limitation on what you can do with WMII via EWMH. [This](http://code.google.com/p/wmii/source/browse/cmd/wmii/ewmh.c) does implement only a subset of the EWMH specification.  You would have to switch to a more compliant window manager for that.

(You seem to be calling wmctrl the right way, BTW)

Comment: Actually I'm not willing to change WM that's why I'm looking for people to try it for me :)

Comment: I can understand that you don't want to change, but I seriously suspect xprop's failure is caused by the limitations of WMII as well.

Comment: That doesn't reply to my question unfortunately.

Comment: @xpixelz The answer seems to be "you can't do this in wmii"